# a fair coin is thrown ten times. find the probability that more heads than tails arise?

Tags: probability

im not sure with this one.

do I use a binomial expansion and add up the results of 6h and 4t + 7H and 3T + 8h and 2t+ 9h and 1t.

help

Answer (score 3):

It's simpler than that actually.

Can you figure out the probability that exactly 5 heads and 5 tails occur?

Then you can use symmetry between the probability that more heads occur, and the probability that more tails occur.

edit:

Let $X$ be the event that more heads occur, $Y$ the event that more tails occur, and $Z$ the event that the number of heads and tails are equal. Then, it is the case that $P(X)+P(Y)+P(Z) = 1$, since these three events cover the entire sample space and are disjoint.

My claim is that $P(X) = P(Y)$ by symmetry. So, if you can figure out $P(Z)$ from the definition of the binomial distribution, then you can solve for $P(X)$.

Comment: probability of 5h and 5t must be a half

Comment: Nope. You need to use binomial distribution.

Comment: ok. i'll try it

Comment: not sure. I ended up with 15.75.

Comment: A probability should be a number between $0$ and $1$. Here, it is $\binom{10}{5}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^5=\frac{63}{256}$.